# redirect all invalid SSL reguest to http in Nginx SSL termination

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

i use nginx for SSL termination before my backend servers as reverse proxy.
i want Redirect all invalid https domain ( have'nt SSL), redirect to http in nginx SSL termination.
I do not want to do this for all sites Separately for each one, I want a general solution for all requests dont have https but open with https and redirect to http Automatically.
i have nginx for SSL termination.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to redirect invalid SSL. Redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP first needs a successful SSL connection so that the redirect can be done at the HTTP level inside the SSL connection. Failing to establish the SSL connection in the first place (because invalid) thus makes it impossible to get to the redirect at the HTTP level.

Comment: I can forward https to http traffic in .htaccess (rewrite rule) when i use apache webserver, how can I do the same job in nginx for a specific domain? ( in custom nginx.conf for a domain address)

Comment: @behnambahadori: this is a different question from your original one. New questions should not be asked in a comment (and also not in an "answer" as you've tried). Apart from that - there is really lots of easy to find documentation online on how to do redirects with nginx and configuration for nginx is usually specific for a domain anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you take off the certificated from a server listening on Port 443, nginx will just start a regular HTTP server on that Port since nginx is Port agnostic.

You have to put a valid cert in the server block of nginx or the client won't do anything defined in the server block including redirects. An "invalid connection" as you say it breaks the connection and it's not possible (luckily) to force a client from HTTPS to HTTP in such a way as you describe it.